# How do I write a cron scheduler to trigger every day at a specific time?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

How do I write a cron scheduler with NestJS so that it triggers every day at 3 am?

```
@Cron('10 * * * * *')
async handleCron() {
    const country = await this.countryRepo.find();
    country.map(async (value) => {
      ...doing something
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
@Cron('0 0 3 * * *')
//     | | | | | | every day of week
//     | | | | | every month
//     | | | | every day of month
//     | | | at 3 hours
//     | | at 0 minutes
//     | at 0 seconds
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#declarative-cron-jobs